# submit form with one submit button inside while loop with array of inputs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit multiple inputs with data using one submit button with an ajax request. However the the response returns an empty array.

What could be the problem?

jQuery

```
$('#setup').click(function(){
  var formData = new FormData(jQuery('#form8')[0]);
  xhr_post(formData,'./ajax/SendUsers.php','SVRMSG');
});
```

PHP and HTML:

```
echo '<form id="form8" method="POST">';

$gen = generateRandomString();
include('connection.php');

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `clients_table`,`client_education_system` WHERE id = edu_client_id  ORDER BY id ASC');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  if ($row['edu_course_D'] == 6 ){
  ?>
  ID: <input style="border:0;" type="text" disabled="disabled" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
  <br>

  Valid Until : <input style="border:0;" disabled="disabled" type="text"  name="valid[]" placeholder="validity date" value="<?php echo getLinks('24'); ?>"/>
  <br>

  Conference date: <input style="border:0;" disabled="disabled" type="text"  name="cdate[]" placeholder="conference date" value="<?php echo getContent('24'); ?>"/>
  <br>

  Serial number : <input style="border:0;" disabled="disabled" type="text" name="serial[]" placeholder="serial" value="<?php echo $row['id'].$gen; ?>"/>
  <br>

  <input   type="text"  name="" value=""/>
  <br>
  <?php
  echo '<center>';
  echo '<button id="cancelSetup" style="background:white;color:red;" type="button" name="cancelsu">Cancel</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
  echo '<button id="setup" style="background:white;color:red;" type="button" >Send</button>';
  echo '<div id="SVRMSG"></div>';
  echo "</form>";
  ?>
```

sendusers.php file

```
<?php
require_once('..\inc\backend-func.php');

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  == 'POST'){
  print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

Comment: Firstly the values of disabled input fields are not submitted with form. Secondly the enabled input you have for user to enter data has no name. Therefore none of the fields are submitting anything. Use readonly (instead of disabled) and give your input fields a name.

Comment: Thankyou it worked !